# After login in the desktop remains blank

Tags: startup

I have installed Ubuntu 10 last night and finished all upgrading stuff, in the time when updates are applied I downloaded a torrent file. As soon as download is finished I rebooted my system. As usual at start up it asked my login and I did the same.

After a successful login It should show me the desktop, or show an error message in case anything has gone wrong. But what I had is only a cursor and a blank wall paper.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem and how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you could possibly add the contents of `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` right after the event to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and provide the links here to help us get some idea what is failing.

Comment: Ok let me say, none of the options worked, I had to reinstall everything. And its been a week since the os runs flawlessly.

Comment: First what is Ubuntu 10 is it 11.10 or 10.10

Comment: Closing it as 'too localized' as the OP solved the problem by reinstalling it.

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem: see [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: In the very rare event you're using Parallel on a Mac, something similar to this happened to me. From Parallels Settings, Hardware->Graphics: I turned off 3D acceleration, and lowered Graphics memory to 32 MB. Everything then worked (after the virtual machine rebooted).

Answer (score 10):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login
3. Type

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   sudo reboot
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Did you fill up your root-partition?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, login and issue:
`df -h`, if that's zero for your rootdevice you'd get the symptons you describe.

It would be helpful to get some logging.

Comment: +1K, Muahhhh...... that did it.. root partition was 100% used... deleted some data and rebooted.. boommmm.. working..

Answer (score 0):

I had (have) the same problem on a Dell D630 and NVIDIA chip and ubuntu 10.10. It only happens if i use ANY of the following:

- NVIDIA proprietary drivers version 280 something. if i revert to 170 something, it is fine
- If i use an updated kernel from the kernel.ubuntu.com site pass 2.39. if i use any 2.38, it works fine.

weird huh?

Try the following,

- Boot into recovery mode (hold on shift while restarting)
- choose to run in failsafe graphics mode for this session only.
- Go to hardware adapters and choose the nvidia 170 something
  (assuming you use nvidia)
- Go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and download
  the 2.6.38.8-natty kernel files
- To install:

  - Open command line and install the *all headers* file, then the
    headers for your architecture (x86, or x64), then the image file for
    your architecture, by using `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`
  - OR, double click on the .deb files on the order mentioned above and
    install them. they should open with gDebi or ubuntu Software center,
    both which will allow you to install them.
- then restart.

I hope this helps. again, just my experience, but i am not an expert by any means.

Answer (score -3):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. `sudo apt-get install update`
3. `sudo startx`